# Creating a Circular Reference Based On Table

Tags: sql, oracle, object, plsql

I have a database with separate tables for national tax rates and county tax rates and I'd like to create objects to represent these that look something like...

```
create type county as object
(
  my_nation nation,
  local_taxRate number
);

create type counties as table of county;

create type nation as object
(
  national_taxRate number
  my_counties counties
);
```

This is impossible though since it creates a circular definition. Is there someway to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjmng.htm#ADOBJ7651

> Types that depend on each other for their definitions, either directly
>   or through intermediate types, are called mutually dependent. For
>   example, you might want to define object types employee and department
>   in such a way that one attribute of employee is the department the
>   employee belongs to and one attribute of department is the employee
>   who manages the department.
>
> If you visualize a diagram with arrows showing the relationships among
>   a set of mutually dependent types, the connections form a loop. **To
>   define such a circular dependency, you must use REFs for at least one
>   segment of the circle.**

You need to use REF somewhere in the definition, for example:

```
create type nation /* empty type placeholder */
/

create type county as object
(
  my_nation REF nation,
  local_taxRate number
);
/

create type counties as table of county
/

/* redefinition of "empty" nation */
create type nation as object
(
  national_taxRate number,
  my_counties counties
)
/
```